# CBPeripheral.ancsAuthorized info is unreliable

Tags: ios, ios13, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager, ancs

Our app works with a paired Bluetooth peripheral that uses ANCS, that is why I dug early into the brand new privacy setting "Share System Notifications" to make our app ready for iOS13... 
However there is an issue, the CBPeripheral property [ancsAuthorized(Bool)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/3180040-ancsauthorized?language=objc) is unreliable, so then it is impossible to know if the user granted the authorization or not. It is unreliable in 2 ways:

1. Once connected to the peripheral, asking
   `peripheral.ancsAuthorized` returns always `false` at first, then after some reconnections it returns always `true`, whatever is set the authorization switch before connecting to it.
2. The second case, when using the new CBCentralManager
   delegate [didUpdateANCSAuthorizationFor:cbperipheral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/3180030-centralmanager?language=objc) : it is fired
   successfully each time I play with the setting switch (located in the iOS > Bluetooth > Device Settings), but
   unfortunately, the result of `peripheral.ancsAuthorized` is always
   `true`, wether I switch the authorization on or off :(

I posted a sysdiagnose file and complete description to the Apple Feedback Assistant, helped by a dedicated support ticket, but so far it remains open with no news at all…

Did anyone had a chance to play with this new privacy setting successfully?

Answer (score 0):

add `CBConnectPeripheralOptionRequiresANCS` to option when connect.

```
centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: [
      CBConnectPeripheralOptionRequiresANCS: true
 ])
```

Comment: This is the right answer. If you are not adding this ANCS option every time you connect to the BT device, then the `ancsAuthorized` call will be inaccurate. Make sure this option is added on each time you connect, not just on initial pairing. Make sure you are connecting on app bootup to catch cases where you app crashes or gets updated to a newer build

Answer (score -1):

It looks like after installing iOS 13.1 beta 2 the problem numner 2 has been fixed by Apple.
However the first issue, that is getting the status of that authorization once connected to a CBPeripheral, is still random, sometimes it returns always true, sometimes always false…

Comment: Tried with 13.1.3, still having the first issue.